# Jinja2 template evaluate variable as attribute

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, eval

I have a Jinja2 Template I'm working on for a database editing app, and I'm trying to make it 'extendible' - rather than hard-coding the editing page, I'm passing a list of attributes that I want in the table, and using a for loop to iterate over them.  It works aside from one thing - in the hardcoded version, I use an attribute of an object that's being passed to see if that value has been set (they are all boolean), but I can't see how to get jinja2 to take the 'capability' and use that as an attribute of the 'pupil' object; i would have used 'eval' in Python, but can't see how to get this to work.  Here's an idea of the code:

```
{%  for capability in capability_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ capability }}</td>
        <td>
            {% if pupil.capability %}
                <img src="{{request.static_url('gdpr_permissions:static/tick.png')}}" width="25">
            {% else %}
                <img src="{{request.static_url('gdpr_permissions:static/cross.png')}}" width="25">
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="onoffswitch">
                <input type="checkbox" name="{{ capability }}" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value ='No' id="{{ capability }}" checked>
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="{{ capability }}">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

It's the `{% if pupil.capability %}` part that doesn't work - I want this to become (say) `pupil.web_access` and `pupil.database_access` etc., following the capability list which is being iterated over.

Any ideas on how to get this working with jinja2, or how else it can be approached?  The other idea I had was to iterate over the current settings in the python backend and then pass a list of booleans separately, but this seems to be adding an extra level of complexity.

Comment: Where are you passing in the *pupil*?? What is in the `capability_list `?? are they attributes of *pupil*??

Comment: the pupil is an object from a class created using sqlalchemy, passed via views.py, and capability_list is a list which has the attributes of the pupil object in - something like ['web_access', 'database_access'] etc.  It was all working fine in the 'long hand coded' version, but it's trying to convert into a Jinja2 for loop to allow expansion of the list of capabilities without having to re-code everything is where it's currently stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are passing in a **string** instead of an attribute. Use `getattr()` instead. Do something like `getattr(pupil, capability)`

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try and report back when I've got it working.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - because of looking further and someone else's question on using `getattr()`, I found that I could do what I wanted with `{% if pupil[capability] %}` to access the attribute directly, with no further changes needed.